# Cannot get a fully JSON using jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm trying to read a json by using jersey api. That's a long json.
The problem is I can't get the full json. Please look at both links below for more understanding.

[Expect result.](http://justpaste.it/mxrh) (10 objects)

[Actual result](http://justpaste.it/mxrk) (Sorry because this one can't be format. But it can only get 4 objects and a bit of the 5th object.)

This is my code to get json:

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource resource = client.resource(url);
    ClientResponse clientResponse = resource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

    if(clientResponse.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + clientResponse.getStatus());
    }

    String output = "";
    String response = "";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (clientResponse.getEntityInputStream())));

    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response = response + output;
    }

    br.close();

    return response;
```

I don't know what I did wrong here.

Comment: Do you store the JSON-String in a Database? If this is true then you have to watch the column-size: TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, etc. had this problem a few month ago and my result looked like yours, so I edited my Database.

Comment: @Nico Nope. I'm not store it in database. Just get it from server and now want to show it on my page. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you c/p the actual result from (console, using sysout; debugger; other frameworks involved)? Have you tried to use a concret response object like MobilePhone.class instead of ClientResponse.class, so the MessageBodyReader can do its job?

Comment: I am pretty sure you are seeing this in the LoggingFilter. The logging filter will truncate the output unless you configure it to print the entire entity. Are you looking at the output in the log output on the server? By the way the ellipsis (...) at the end of the output is a dead give away that your output is being truncated.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw Seem like you are right.
Thank you all for your comment.

Comment: Nice that i was able to give the correct hint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is receiving the full output. You are seeing the truncated output in the log because the LoggingFilter that you have enabled by default will truncate the output.

Check the constructors here for how to set the maxEntitySize.

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html